# Database design for a organization hierarchy

Tags: database, database-design

I have a simple use case where I've got the following data model for an Organization.

```
Org Details
===========
Org Id
Org Name
Org Type
```

What I would like to do is setup a nested Organization hierarchy so I can create a nested parent > child relationship between multiple Organizations. In other words, one parent organization will have multiple sub organizations. I thought of modelling it like so,

```
Org Hierarchy
=============
relationshipId
parentOrg   -------- Org Details(1)
subOrg      -------- Org Details(*)
```

*-------- signifies the one-to-one and one-to-many mapping*

Am I approaching this the right way ? or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recording a parent-child relationship in a separate table is a valid way of solving this. However, you don't need a surrogate `relationshipId` as primary key. Since each sub-organization can only have a single parent organization, `subOrg` is a suitable primary key. Alternatively, you can add a nullable `parentOrg` column to `Org Details`.

Comment: Im also wondering how Many-to-many relationship would work in this case ?

Comment: A many-to-many relationship would require its own table. For the primary key, I'd use a composite key containing both parentOrg and subOrg.